# Different PDO behaviours between PHP versions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have three servers running as my development, staging and production servers. The PHP version running are: `5.5.23`, `5.5.9`, `5.5.20` respectively.

They are running exactly the same code. But my development server was throwing exceptions whereas the other two works fine. The exception is follow:

> Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'comment_id' at row 1
>       Request URL: /comments/add.json
>       Stack Trace:
>       0 /Users/me/Sites/MySite/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(460): PDOStatement->execute(Array)1
>       1 /Users/me/Sites/MySite/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(426): DboSource->_execute('INSERT INTO `po...', Array)1
>       2 /Users/me/Sites/MySite/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(1008): DboSource->execute('INSERT INTO `po...')1
>       3 /Users/me/Sites/MySite/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(1744): DboSource->create(Object(Notification), Array, Array)1
>       4 /Users/me/Sites/MySite/app/Controller/CommentsController.php(181): Model->save(Array)1
>       5 [internal function]: CommentsController->add()

The value being inserted is a `bool(false)` while the database is expecting integers. So I had to do something like to handle this issue for my development server:

```
//The comment id is set to false. Needs to turn it to NULL as DB can't handle false for integer
if($this->Comment->id === false)
    $notification['Notification']['comment_id'] = NULL;
else
    $notification['Notification']['comment_id'] = $this->Comment->id;
```

My question is: Why my staging and production server can handle this issue (auto-convert the false value into integer, possibly), but my development server cannot?

As you can see, my servers are running `CakePHP`. I have been looking at the PDO versions but it seemed like it doesn't give me too much insight. My development server is running on my Mac Book Mac OS X 10.10. The staging and production are running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @MartinKonecny MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely have strict mode for MySQL disabled on your Production and Staging environments, while your development environment has this enabled.

[See more here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html):

> Strict mode controls how MySQL handles invalid or missing values in data-change statements such as INSERT or UPDATE. A value can be invalid for several reasons. For example, it might have the wrong data type for the column, or it might be out of range. A value is missing when a new row to be inserted does not contain a value for a non-NULL column that has no explicit DEFAULT clause in its definition. (For a NULL column, NULL is inserted if the value is missing.)
>
> **If strict mode is not in effect, MySQL inserts adjusted values for invalid or missing values and produces warnings**

You can read on [how to change this mode here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting).

On OS X, the [following link has more details](http://stanlemon.net/2013/03/23/mysql-strict-mode-on-os-x/):

> After a lot of poking around I found out that MySQL for OS X from Oracle ships with a /usr/local/mysql/my.cnf which is loaded on startup. In this file is a sole configuration directive for sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES.  Once I commented this out and restarted the server strict mode was off, my ORM worked and I was happy.

Comment: Exactly what is happening! You're the man Martin! Thanks a lot.